# Surfaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ invariant by an affine map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, surfaces

I have a rather elementary question.

I would like to know what are the surfaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are globally preserved by the action of a linear or affine map in a non trivial way. This question is voluntarily vague.

Obvious example of such surfaces are linear planes and the level sets of quadratic form. So my questions unfold the following way:

1. Do 'exotic' surfaces invariant by an element $A \in \mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ exist? (in the sense that it is neither a plane nor a level set of a quadratic form)
2. Are there example of such surfaces which are invariant by a Lie subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{R}^3)$?
3. If such a surface $\Sigma$ exists, is the action of an element $A \in \mathrm{GL}(3,\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ determined by its value at a point $p$ and by $A_{|T_p\Sigma}$?
4. Can one list all such surfaces?

Immersed or degenerated surfaces would be interesting to me as well. Any reference is welcome! Thanks :)

Comment: Surfaces of revolution give an example for questions 1. and 2. Also, the surface $(x^2+y^2)z^2 = 1$ is invariant under a two-dimensional subgroup generated by rotations around the $z$-axis and $(x,y,z) \mapsto (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda^{-1} z)$.

Answer (score 1):

For immersed surfaces, take your favorite surface $S$ and your favorite affine map $\gamma$ and look at the $\Gamma$-orbit of $S$ (where $\Gamma = \langle \gamma \rangle)$.In particular, the case where $\gamma$ is an involution gives you a boat-load of examples. Otherwise, take an arbitrary curve and look at its image under a one-dimensional Lie subgroup of $Aff(3).$ An embedded example is the orbit by translations in the $z$ direction of an arbitrary curve in the $xy$-plane. Otherwise, take an orbit of a discrete point set under a two dimensional subgroup...

Comment: You might be more generous and allow simultaneous rotation and translation of plane curves, to produce helicoids as the easiest example.

Comment: @SebastianGoette True enough!